# Grails. Executing commands on console

Tags: grails

Hello im trying to run some commands in my windows console via grails. Ive this code

```
def pruebaMail() {
    "mkdir C:\\pruebaMail".execute()
                 }
```

but it doesnt create the folder, any ideas about how to make it work? i want to try this also in linux since i need to use a terminal command to send mails.

Comment: ugh! please don't do this... use the [mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) to send mails, and [File](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html) to create files/dirs

Comment: Sometimes project requirements define the need to use things outside of the standard, easy way of being done. Not OPs fault.

Comment: Hello moeTi, i tried to use the mail plugin, but i need to send mails with headers for outlook, the main idea is to send meetings that autoagend on the calendars recievers (without even opnening the mail), i tried to do so in the mail plugin but it was unsuccesful

Answer (score 1):

In windows you have to preface that:

```
"cmd /c mkdir C:\\pruebaMail".execute()
```

I'm assuming you read: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy